# Conemu recommends using Admin mode, when it's already being used

Tags: admin, sikuli, conemu

I'm running it as an Admin, but it's saying.

```
"Possible cause in case you did not touch the mouse while script was running:
Mouse actions are blocked generally or by the frontmost application.
You might try to run the SikuliX stuff as admin."
```

So not sure how to disable this feature as it's definitely running as an Admin.

Comment: This is not a message from ConEmu.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, this is not a ConEmu message, this is SikuliX message. To confirm this, you can try running your script from Windows command line while launching the cmd terminal as Admin. This will both, ensure that you are running as Admin and verify the actual reason why you are getting this message.